# How to plot waves representing wireless link connection and set the exact width of a box from one point to another

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, width

The following diagram represents two devices connecting wirelessly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,fit,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,positioning}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick, node 
distance=7em, 
text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=3.5em}}
%\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -{Latex[length=2mm,width=1mm]}}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%=======================================
% Adjust the boarder of the flowchart
%=======================================
\setlength\PreviewBorder{4pt}%

\begin{document}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Define block styles
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\tikzset{
block/.style={rectangle split, draw, rectangle split parts=2,text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
brwblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=brown!20, text width=13em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em, minimum width=30em}, 
whtblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, text width=14em, text centered, minimum height=4em},  
vertblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=cyan!20, text width=17em, text centered, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em},   
line/.style={draw, {latex[length=5mm,width=5mm]}-{latex[length=5mm,width=5mm]}},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=white!20, node distance=3cm,    minimum height=4em},  
% container/.style={draw, rectangle,dashed,inner sep=0.28cm, rounded corners,fill=yellow!20,minimum height=4cm}}
container1/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.4cm,fill=blue!8,minimum height=4cm,rounded corners},
container2/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.28cm,fill=green!10,minimum height=4em,rounded corners}}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25cm, auto,every text node part/.style={align=center}]
%
%===============================================    
%  Reader
%===============================================  
  \node [whtblock,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=magenta!15] (LBT) {LBT \\[0.5em]Reader Anti-Collision Protocol};   
  \node [whtblock, below=of LBT, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=green!15] (FSA) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};
  \node [whtblock, below=of FSA, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=yellow!20] (PHY) {PHY Layer};
  \node [whtblock, below=of PHY, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (AT) {Active Transceiver};
%*****************
% TAG
%***************

  \node [whtblock, right=of AT, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,shift={(2.8cm,0)}] (PTtag) {Passive Transceiver};
  \node [whtblock, above=of PTtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=yellow!20] (PHYtag) {PHY Layer};

  \node [whtblock, above=of PHYtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=green!15] (FSAtag) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};

  \node [vertblock, right=of PHYtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,shift={(0cm,3.7cm)},fill=pink!30,rotate=-90] (EHtag) {Energy Harvester};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   CONTAINERS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=3mm]LBT.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux1) (FSA)(PHY)(AT)] (Reader) {};
  \node at (Reader.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Reader}};
%-----------------------------------------------------------
  \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=3mm]FSAtag.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux2) (PHYtag)(FSAtag)(PTtag)(EHtag)] (TAG) {};
  \node at (TAG.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Tag}};
\end{scope}

 \node[brwblock,shift={(0,8.0cm)},minimum width=18cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] at ($(Reader)!.5!(TAG)$) {\textbf{Scenario Setup}};

%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Draw edges
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (LBT.south) -- (FSA.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (FSA.south) -- (PHY.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (PHY.south) -- (AT.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (FSAtag.south) -- (PHYtag.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (PTtag.north) -- (PHYtag.south);

\draw [-Latex,darkgray,very thick] ([yshift=6pt]AT.east) -- node [above,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {Power-Up \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=6pt]PTtag.west);
\draw [-Latex,darkgray,very thick] ([yshift=-6pt]PTtag.west) -- node [below,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {Backscattered \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=-6pt]AT.east);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= -10pt]PTtag.east) -- ([yshift=-94pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [-Latex,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= +10pt]PTtag.east) -- ([yshift=-74pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= 0pt]PHYtag.east) -- ([yshift=-1pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= 0pt]PHYtag.east) -- ([yshift=-1pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= 0pt]FSAtag.east) -- ([yshift=82pt]EHtag.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to replace horizontal arrows of labels "Power-Up Link" and "Backscattered Link" by curves representing waves attenuating with distance, like the ones I have sketched by hand. 
The amplitude of the wave should be greater in the Power-up Link than in the Backscattered Link.
I do not know how to make this, and I have not found any similar plot.

Besides, I would like to ask how to set the exact width of "Scenario Setup" box cover from the left side of the Reader container to the right side of the Tag container. I have been testing values of `minimum width=` in `\node[brwblock,shift={(0,8.0cm)},minimum width=18cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] at ($(Reader)!.5!(TAG)$) {\textbf{Scenario Setup}};` but it does not fit the width of both containers.

The Energy Harvester box has the same issue. I would like to expand this box from the top of FSA to the bottom of Passive Transceiver, but it is tough to match this length using `text width=` of the `vertblock` style.

Similarly,  I have adjusted `yshift`values of the arrow lines between the Energy Harvester box and the rest of boxes to be horizontal, but it is difficult to determine what is the matching yshift to make a horizontal arrow pointing from this box to FSA and PHY Layer, and Passive Transceiver boxes.

I do not know if these questions can be answered in one question or I should ask separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `expanding waves` decoration and clip the unwanted pieces away.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,fit,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick, node 
distance=7em, 
text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=3.5em}}
%\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -{Latex[length=2mm,width=1mm]}}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%=======================================
% Adjust the boarder of the flowchart
%=======================================
\setlength\PreviewBorder{4pt}%

\begin{document}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Define block styles
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\tikzset{
block/.style={rectangle split, draw, rectangle split parts=2,text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
brwblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=brown!20, text width=13em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em, minimum width=30em}, 
whtblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, text width=14em, text centered, minimum height=4em},  
vertblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=cyan!20, text width=17em, text centered, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em},   
line/.style={draw, {latex[length=5mm,width=5mm]}-{latex[length=5mm,width=5mm]}},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=white!20, node distance=3cm,    minimum height=4em},  
% container/.style={draw, rectangle,dashed,inner sep=0.28cm, rounded corners,fill=yellow!20,minimum height=4cm}}
container1/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.4cm,fill=blue!8,minimum height=4cm,rounded corners},
container2/.style={draw, rectangle,inner sep=0.28cm,fill=green!10,minimum height=4em,rounded corners}}
%************************************************************
%************************************************************ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25cm, auto,every text node part/.style={align=center}]
%
%===============================================    
%  Reader
%===============================================  
  \node [whtblock,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=magenta!15] (LBT) {LBT \\[0.5em]Reader Anti-Collision Protocol};   
  \node [whtblock, below=of LBT, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=green!15] (FSA) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};
  \node [whtblock, below=of FSA, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=yellow!20] (PHY) {PHY Layer};
  \node [whtblock, below=of PHY, node distance=2.5cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] (AT) {Active Transceiver};
%*****************
% TAG
%***************

  \node [whtblock, right=of AT, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,shift={(2.8cm,0)}] (PTtag) {Passive Transceiver};
  \node [whtblock, above=of PTtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=yellow!20] (PHYtag) {PHY Layer};

  \node [whtblock, above=of PHYtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,fill=green!15] (FSAtag) {FSA \\[0.5em]Anti-Collision Protocol};

  \node [vertblock, right=of PHYtag, node distance=13cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont,shift={(0cm,3.7cm)},fill=pink!30,rotate=-90] (EHtag) {Energy Harvester};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   CONTAINERS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=3mm]LBT.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux1) (FSA)(PHY)(AT)] (Reader) {};
  \node at (Reader.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Reader}};
%-----------------------------------------------------------
  \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=3mm]FSAtag.north);
  \node [container1,fit=(aux2) (PHYtag)(FSAtag)(PTtag)(EHtag)] (TAG) {};
  \node at (TAG.north) [fill=white,draw,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {\textbf{Tag}};
\end{scope}

 \node[brwblock,shift={(0,8.0cm)},minimum width=18cm,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] at ($(Reader)!.5!(TAG)$) {\textbf{Scenario Setup}};

%************************************************************
%************************************************************
%  Draw edges
%************************************************************
%************************************************************
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (LBT.south) -- (FSA.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (FSA.south) -- (PHY.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (PHY.south) -- (AT.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (FSAtag.south) -- (PHYtag.north);
\draw [Latex-Latex,darkgray, thick] (PTtag.north) -- (PHYtag.south);

\draw [-Latex,darkgray,very thick] ([yshift=6pt]AT.east) -- node [above,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {Power-Up \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=6pt]PTtag.west);
\draw [-Latex,darkgray,very thick] ([yshift=-6pt]PTtag.west) -- node [below,font=\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont] {Backscattered \\[0.5em] Link} ([yshift=-6pt]AT.east);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= -10pt]PTtag.east) -- ([yshift=-94pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [-Latex,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= +10pt]PTtag.east) -- ([yshift=-74pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= 0pt]PHYtag.east) -- ([yshift=-1pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= 0pt]PHYtag.east) -- ([yshift=-1pt]EHtag.south);
\draw [Latex-,darkgray, thick] ([yshift= 0pt]FSAtag.east) -- ([yshift=82pt]EHtag.south);
\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=12pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=20}] 
([yshift=12pt]AT.center) --([yshift=6pt]PTtag.west);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift=-12pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=-8pt]AT.east)
-- ([yshift=-4pt]PTtag.west);
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=20}] 
([yshift=-8pt]PTtag.center) --([yshift=-8pt]AT.east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I replace the upper clip scope by

```
\begin{scope}
\clip[postaction=draw] ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=14pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=10pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=20}] 
([yshift=12pt]AT.center) --([yshift=6pt]PTtag.west);
\end{scope}
```

I get

[image]

so the wave is wider at the point it where it arrives, i.e. the right box. The second way to interpret your comment is to make the incoming upper wave wider at the point it arrives then the lower wave at the point it departs. This can be done e.g. by

```
\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=15pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=9pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=20}] 
([yshift=12pt]AT.center) --([yshift=6pt]PTtag.center);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift=-12pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=-9pt]AT.east) --([yshift=-7pt]AT.east)
-- ([yshift=-4pt]PTtag.west);
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=20}] 
([yshift=-8pt]PTtag.center) --([yshift=-8pt]AT.east);
\end{scope}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I control the size of the wave?. For example, I would like the Power-Up wave size arriving at the Passive Transceiver be a little bigger than the first backscattered wave.

Comment: @user1993416 you only have to adjust the `\clip` path, e.g. `\clip ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=14pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=10pt]PTtag.west)  --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);`. For debugging, it often helps to say `\clip[postaction=draw] ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=14pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=10pt]PTtag.west)  --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);` or just `\draw ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=14pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=10pt]PTtag.west)  --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);` to see what's going on.

Comment: I apologize, but I have tested those clips and make changes in the yshift parameter but it changes the direction of the decoration but does not control how I can control the size of the wave. I think I do not understand the clip command.

Comment: @user1993416 Sorry, most likely some misunderstanding. I added a screen shot of what this clip gives me (with the contour drawn). Most likely I misread your request. Could you please try to rephrase it?

Comment: I think I know how to control the width of the wave. Thank you. Does the angle parameter control the curvature of the waves?. I would like to test with a little more curvature.

Comment: It was the second interpretation: Make the wave wider at the arriving point.

Comment: @user1993416 As far as I know the angle is only the opening angle. You can increase the curvature by moving the ficticious emitter, which is currently at `([yshift=12pt]AT.center)` to the right, e.g. `([yshift=12pt,xshift=2cm]AT.center)` and then also increasing angle. Of course, you can also draw these waves without decorations. And thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You could also do `\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=15pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=9pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);
\draw[red,thick] 
foreach \X in {1,...,15}
{([yshift=12pt,xshift=-2mm]AT.east) ellipse(\X*3mm and {(3+\X)*1mm})};
\end{scope}` if you want to have more/full control over the curvature.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try with this `\clip ([yshift=24pt]AT.east) --([yshift=18pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=12pt]PTtag.west)--([yshift=6pt]PTtag.west) --([yshift=0pt]AT.east);
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=20}]
([yshift=12pt,xshift=0.5cm]AT.center) --([yshift=6pt]PTtag.west);`. What does the angle=20 do?. I have been changing the value an it seems change nothing.

Comment: @user1993416 If you remove the clip command, you can see the impact of the angle. It is described on p. 633 of the pgfmanual.

Comment: Thank you. I will post a new question for the size of the "scenario setup" box to match the extremes of the reader and tag containers.